# How to find the tau permutation that yields a given conjugation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am trying to understand in standard terms the example that is used to explain conjugation of permutations in [here](https://youtu.be/X63MWZIN3gM?t=2760). Since the explanation is trying to avoid any prior knowledge of conjugation, it is hard to reproduce in a short, concise way, but it is based on shuffling cards that are indexed by the numbers in the gray rows (below), followed by relabeling. The steps are summarized in the presentation as follows:

[image]

The stacked-up notation (presumably) would be

$$\begin{align}
\sigma  &=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\; 1 \; 2 \; 3 \; 4  \\
2 \; 4 \; 1 \; 0  \; 3
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}  &=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\; 1 \; 2 \; 3 \; 4  \\
1 \; 3 \; 4 \; 2  \; 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align}$$

with $\sigma$ being the original permutation, and $\tau$ the permutation that outputs the conjugation.

In cycle notation

$$\begin{align}
\sigma &=(0 \; 2 \; 1 \; 4 \; 3)\\
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} &=(0 \; 1 \; 3 \; 2 \; 4)
\end{align}$$

If this makes any sense, what would be the permutation $\tau$ used in the conjugation?

As per the comment, Tau can be obtained by stacking up

$$\begin{bmatrix}\begin{align}\sigma= (0\,2\,1\,4\,3)\\\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(0\,1\,3\,2\,4)
\end{align}\end{bmatrix}\implies
\tau =(2\,1\,3\,4)
$$

For this to be concordant with the card game on the presentation the first row (first permutation given) should be understood as $0$ moves to slot number $3$; $1$ moves to slot number $2$; $\quad 2 \to 0; \quad 3 \to 4; \quad 4 \to 1$, which would result in

$$\sigma=(0\,3\,4\,1\,2)$$

And, similarly,

$$\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(0\,4\,2\,3\,1)$$

which makes it all fall in place when stacking them up to get tau:

$$\tau=(0)\,(3\,4\,2\,1).$$

Comment: It would be (2134) or the inverse of that, depending on whether permutations computed left-to-right or right-to-left.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you. That made clear the actual "algorithm" involved in the concept - it is not composing on the left by the inverse of the permutation $tau$ and on the right by $tau$ performing $\sigma$ in the center, but instead, carrying out $\tau$ on both the input $0 1 2 3 4$ and output $24103$ of the $\sigma$ permutation! The $\tau^{-1}$ is confusing. How did you get the $\tau$?

Comment: There's a trick to get the $\tau$ to go from one cycle to another. It works when both cycles involve the same symbols, for yours 0,1,2,3,4. You then line up one cycle over the other, and read the resulting two rows as if it were a usual permutation in stacked form. I chose to go the extra step and express that in cycle format. If you try itr out on some made-up examples it becomes clear.

Comment: @coffeemath So it would be $\sigma = (0\,2\,1\,4\,3)$ and $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(0\,1\,3\,2\,1)$. Stack them up: $\begin{bmatrix} (0\,2\,1\,4\,3)\\(0\,1\,3\,2\,1)\end{bmatrix}$ and construct $\tau$ in cycle form by reading $0\to0\; 2 \to 1 \; 1 \to 3\; 3 \to 4\; 4 \to 1,$ i.e. $\tau = (0)\,(2\, 1 \, 3 \, 4).$ This is magic! Do you agree that the notation $\tau^{-1}$ is confusing since it is $\tau$ (not the inverse) applied at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: In your last comment you have the method exactly. [I was always amazed it works also] Note that you *need* both $\tau$ and its inverse for $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ to be equal to what you want. You can't use $\tau$ at *both* ends unless $\tau = \tau^{-1}$ i.e. $\tau^2=id.$

Comment: @coffeemath Is the connection between the answer you gave me in your first comment and the cards in the youtube video quoted so self-evident that I will pull my hair when I finally see it? I'm trying to find the correspondence between tau and the shuffling and relabeling of cards, and I don't see it.

Comment: JAP The method I applied was just a way to obtain the $\tau$ used in the conjugation carrying one permutation to another conjugate to it. I don't follow the version of the youtube video, don't know what they were trying to do.